# Reading a text file into a linked list without an array as a buffer?

Tags: c, linked-list

I've been stuck on this problem for a few days now. I'm trying to scan (line by line) a text file of integers directly into a linked list (with the ultimate goal of sorting them). Normally, I would go about it like this...

```
struct list {
    int data;
    struct list *next;
};

int main()
{
    char buffer[100];
    struct list* node = NULL;
FILE *fp = fopen(filename,"r");
while (fgets(buffer, 100, fp)) {

    struct list* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
    new_node->next = NULL;

    new_node->data = atoi(buffer);
}
//and so on...
```

However, I'm not permitted to use arrays for this problem. I'm lost for ways on how to store the buffer at this point.

Am I still approaching this in the right way? Could someone possibly point me in the right direction towards solving this? Note I'm also still fairly new to the concepts of linked lists and structures, etc. Any examples would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Then use `fscanf` instead of `fgets` -

```
struct list* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct list));
new_node->next = NULL;
while (fscanf(fp,"%d",&new_node->data)==1) {    //this will directly store integer into linked list
     //handle your data
     //increment new_node to new_node->next in order to create a list 

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I did not know that was possible, actually. Does this mean that I should append a "[i]" to all of my node operations under the while loop? 

e.g.

        new_node[i]->next=NULL;
        new_node[i]->node[i].data = value;

Comment: @Rewindings  Actually no , not in that . You need to create new nodes as you do and store in them like this .`new_node[i]->next=NULL; new_node[i]->node[i].data = value;` In this `[i]` is not needed .

Comment: @Rewindings Actually that was not needed (_made that change_) .  Main thing is that increment to next node in `while` loop in order to directly read and store value in your linked list . **Edit**-  How is data stored in your file (I mean format ) ?

Comment: Hello again. So if I am correct, all I must do is continue creating the linked list as normal within the while loop? And the new data will be scanned to the next node as normal at the start of the next cycle? The integers are stored line-by-line in the txt file such as:

`87  

45  

22`
(separated by \n's; it is hard to format in the comments :p)
Thank you again for your help :)

Comment: @Rewindings Yes , then you should continue with the loop and create your linked list inside `while` loop . As loop will stop as soon as `EOF` is reached . Then at last set last node's next to `NULL` . in this way can would be able to directly create list. But you may to take a moment in how to create new node  and handle if it is `head`.

Comment: Much thanks! I just got back to doing this problem today and I've successfully gotten the list to generate and display. Thank you again! I really appreciate it!

(If possible, perhaps you could help me a bit with my next error as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060471/sorting-a-linked-list-generated-from-a-file)